# Install sublime text 3 on digitalocean droplet running ubuntu os

Tags: dpkg

Using Ubuntu for the first time and getting some errors that I would appreciate help with.

First two commands to get Sublime Text 3 installed work just fine:

```
$ sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/sublime-text-3
$ sudo apt-get update
```

Error occurs when I run this:

```
$ sudo apt-get install sublime-text-installer 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
sublime-text-installer is already the newest version.
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  linux-headers-3.13.0-32 linux-headers-3.13.0-32-generic
  linux-headers-3.13.0-36 linux-headers-3.13.0-36-generic
  linux-image-3.13.0-32-generic linux-image-3.13.0-36-generic
  linux-image-extra-3.13.0-32-generic linux-image-extra-3.13.0-36-generic
Use 'apt-get autoremove' to remove them.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 3 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] Y
Setting up sublime-text-installer (3083-1~webupd8~0) ...
cp: cannot stat ‘/var/cache/sublime-text/sublime_text_3/*’: No such file or directory
dpkg: error processing package sublime-text-installer (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 sublime-text-installer
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Confirmed that `/var/cache/sublime-text` exists.

cd into `/var/cache/sublime-text` and saw this: 
`sublime_text_3_build_3083_x64.tar.bz2`

Notice that there isn't a `sublime_text_3` directory in there.

Should I: 
`mkdir -p /var/cache/sublime-text/sublime_text_3/` and place `sublime_text_3_build_3083_x64.tar.bz2` inside that directory? My guess is that it is looking for `/var/cache/sublime-text/sublime_text_3/` so that it can run some executable file (which I think is `sublime_text_3_build_3083_x64.tar.bz2`).

Any feedback would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Does the package from http://www.sublimetext.com/3 have the same problem?

Comment: thanks @muru! I don't know because I didn't know that there was a different way to get sublime-text-3. 

This is the right command to run to get the package you mentioned above:
` 
wget http://c758482.r82.cf2.rackcdn.com/sublime_text_3_build_3083_x32.tar.bz2` ?

Ask because I tried it and got a different error.

Comment: No, there are .deb packages for Ubuntu listed on that page. Click on the Ubuntu x64 link.

Comment: @muru thanks for helping me out. 

I did click on the link but it attemps to download a file onto my physical labtop.  My Ubutu is running on a virtual server via DigitalOcean so not sure that is what I want.  Am I right?

Comment: You can copy that link and run `wget` on it, or download the file and then scp to the server. Either way, stick to the deb file instead of the tar.bz2 file.

Comment: I have exactly the same issue. Did you guys ever solve this?

Comment: does it have something to do with `ssh` and using it without the GUI?

Comment: @S.Matthew_English: Hello! I found out I couldn't use sublime text because it doesn't have a GUI.  Was told to learn/use vim instead. 

Did you find out the same?

Comment: yeah. dammit. I guess I need to learn vim too.

Comment: yeah, I want to learn vim but I am already learning so many new things at this point and need to focus; not sure its best to tack on vim.  Will add to do list :)

Answer (score 1):

1. cd to /var/cache/sublime-text
2. bzip2 and untar sublime_text_3_build_3083_x64.tar.bz2
3. Re-run apt-get install
4. Run SublimeText: /usr/bin/subl